# how to sort case insensitive using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

Does `jq` support case insensitive sorting?

for instance I have `data.json` like this

```json
[
  {"title": "first", "description": "foo"},
  {"title": "Second", "description": "bar"}
]
```

simple `jq 'sort_by(.title)' data.json` returns

```json
[
  {"title": "Second", "description": "bar"},
  {"title": "first", "description": "foo"}
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

actually `jq` has built-in filters `ascii_downcase` and `ascii_upcase` you can use like this `jq 'sort_by(.title | ascii_downcase)' data.json` to get proper result.

```json
[
  {"title": "first", "description": "foo"},
  {"title": "Second", "description": "bar"}
]
```

Comment: ( Using `jq 'sort_by(.title|ascii_upcase)'` work same and save 2 characters! ;-)